# How to indicate that a function should use its default value of an optional argument without omitting it?

Tags: python, optional-arguments

I am trying to write code that does not repeat itself, following the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Consider a function call with many arguments, both mandatory and optional. In some cases, I would like to specify a value for an optional argument, whereas in other cases I would like to leave that value to its default value. To simplify my problem:

```
def func(a, b=2):
    print("b = {}".format(b))

avalue = 1
condition = 2
arg = None  # <-- Means: "use default" 
if condition == 1:
    arg = 3

func(avalue, b=arg)
```

**Output**:

```
b = None
```

**Expected output**:

```
b = 2
```

Thus, I am trying to avoid coding the function call twice like this:

```
if arg:
    func(avalue, b=arg)
else:
    func(avalue)
```

Is it possible in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary, and only set the optional argument as a key-value pair in that if you want to specify it. Then apply the dictionary using the `**kwargs` call syntax:

```
avalue = 1
condition = 2

kwargs = {}
if condition == 1:
    kwargs['b'] = 3

func(avalue, **kwargs)
```

An empty dictionary (the `condition != 1` case) leaves `b` set to the default value.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions can be:

```
def func(a, b=2, **kwargs):
    print("b = {}".format(b))

avalue = 1
condition = 2

func(avalue, **{} if condition != 1 else {'b':3})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    b = 2 if not b else b
    print("b = {}".format(b))

avalue = 1
condition = 2
arg = None  # <-- Means: "use default"
if condition == 1:
    arg = 3

func(avalue, arg)  # b = 2
```

and if `condition = 1`:

```
func(avalue, arg)  #  b = 3
```

The above assumes you can modify the function definition. If that is not the case you have to go with `**kwargs`.

Comment: In most cases I would prefer this over the `**kwargs` trick. Stuff in the stdlib does this. with `if b is None: b = 2` though

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if not b:
        b = 2
    print("b = {}".format(b))

avalue = 1
condition = 2
arg = None  # <-- Means: "use default" 
if condition == 1:
    arg = 3

func(avalue, b=arg)
```

At this point however the default isn't really used the way it should be,
defaults are usually kept for when you have two different methods, one that works in a way that the other shouldn't for example for addition/subtraction with a switch:

```
def maths(a,b,sub=false):
    result = a + b
    if sub:
        result = a - b
    return result
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I cannot modify `func` since it is a library function

Answer (score 0):

Op has mentioned that the function func can't be modified so my sugguestion would be :

```
def func(a, b=2):
    print("b = {}".format(b))

avalue = 1
condition = 2
if condition == 1:
    func(avalue, b=3)
else:
    func(avalue)
```